# How can I call a Stored Procedure using Blue Prism?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, package, blueprism

I need to call a package using Blue Prism. I need to give it an input parameter. I can run this on SQL navigator but unable to using Blue Prism. What format is required for Blue Prism

```
Declare
    req  Clob := '{"ItemID":"12345678","splitRawAct":"0"}';
    resp Clob;
Begin
    resp := dbo.pkg_order_Transaction.get_order_history (req);
    dbms_output.put_line (resp);
 
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a SQL query, you should be able to use the data SQL server object to form a connection to your database (with correct connection string) then pass this is in to be executed and get a response from it. I don't think it'll need updating/formatting based on your query here but the data SQL object should be your go to start for getting this query to run against any database. There are a group of actions 'Begin transaction' 'commit transaction' 'rollback transaction' which might be the ones you are looking for.

If your stored procedure is already there i.e. already written you can also just use execute action to run the stored procedure with syntax like

```
proc_name param1, param2
```

which will run the stored procedure with the supplied params